# Using Image rotator with jcarousel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I am trying to integrate two jquery plugins together with no success, The two plugins which i am using is: [simple jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html) & [image rotator](http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/) , below is the code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Show Banner
    $(".main_image .desc").show(); //Show Banner
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0.85 }, 1); //Set Opacity

    //Click and Hover events for thumbnail list
    $(".image_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active');
    $(".image_thumb ul li").click(function () {
        //Set Variables
        var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //Get Alt Tag of Image
        var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); //Get Main Image URL
        var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();    //Get HTML of block
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height(); //Calculate height of block   

        if ($(this).is(".active")) {  //If it's already active, then...
            return false; // Don't click through
        } else {
            //Animate the Teaser                
            $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250, function () {
                $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85, marginBottom: "0" }, 250);
                //$(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle, alt: imgAlt });
                //                   
            });
        }

        $(".image_thumb ul li").removeClass('active'); //Remove class of 'active' on all lists
        $(this).addClass('active');  //add class of 'active' on this list only
        return false;

    }).hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    //Toggle Teaser
    $("a.collapse").click(function () {
        $(".main_image .block").slideToggle();
        $("a.collapse").toggleClass("show");
    });

});  //Close Function
 </script> 

  <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});

 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

 <div id="main" class="container"> 
<div class="main_image"> 


    <div class="desc"> 
        <a href="#" class="collapse">Close Me!</a> 
        <div class="block"> 
            <h2>Slowing Down</h2> 
            <small>04/10/09</small> 

            <p> </p> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<div class="image_thumb"> 
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a href="#"><img src="images/nav2a.png" alt="Slowing Dow" /></a> 
            <div class="block"> 



                <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango"> 
                <li>a</li> 
                <li>b</li> 
                <li>c</li> 
                <li>d</li> 
                <li>e</li> 


              </ul>

              </div>


        </li> 
    </ul> 
</div> 
 </div>
```

Image rotator is working fine but the jcarousel is not working within the image rotator it works fine outside the image rotator , Any help or advice or any other alternative will be appreciated, my jquery expertise = beginner. Regarding the stuff which i m looking for on the website is just a image rotator and within that image there should be subpages with arrow buttons like jcarousel.

Answer (score -1):

You can't mix two plugins directly, for that you have to change some code.